# Open back of Toshiba Satellite L855

Tags: laptop, toshiba-laptop

I have a Toshiba Satellite L855 - S5372. I was using it when it suddenly started making a wack-wack-wack noise; I'm certain that something got stuck in the CPU fan. Nothing had come in from the outside, and rocking it failed to change anything. I thought it would be a simple matter to take the cover off of the back and remove whatever is in the fan, but after removing 20-something screws and getting the cover loose, the cover seems to be caught near the battery compartment (the battery is removed).

Can anyone tell me if:

- There's a secret latch or something where the cover goes around the battery compartment.
- There are any actual service manuals, diagrams, etc. on the Internet. Google searches have only found "user manuals" with really basic software stuff.

I have some experience working on the inside of desktop computers, but laptop repair is new to me.

Comment: Here's a take apart video for a similar model: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Az23GUmKt2s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get the back cover off, you need to remove a smaller cover in the middle of it and remove the hard drive, which is below that. Once the hard drive is out, the cover swivels back enough for the latches near the battery compartment to be undone.

Comment: Asked and answered by the same person? Is the issue resolved?

Comment: @Prasanna: yes. I'm writing this comment from the problem computer! Like I said in my question, I'm used to PCs and it seemed completely wrong to have to take the hard drive out in order to remove the cover. I didn't even realize that was a possibility until after I posted the question.